# Unable to Merge

Tags: bitbucket

As regular user of bitbucket never face this problem before. Created Pull Request in regular way and when trying to merge it throws error without any details about reasons. Tried for several days with gap in between and also tried in different timing. What will be the reason and how to solve it.

[image: Pull request unable to merge]

Comment: This usually happens when your pull request needs manual merging. Post the entire message, as usually it also adds hints on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes usually it will show details but this time it shows only messages provided in screenshot in question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know any details about the error, just merge your branches in your command line:

```
git merge my-feature-branch
git push --all
```

(run this in the branch where you want `my-feature-branch` to be merged)

---

Also, if you consider so, you can always open an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/new).

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533093/bitbucket-unable-to-merge-this-field-is-required/42533490?noredirect=1#comment72202780_42533490

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it also works when we open bitbucket instance in incognito.