# bitbucket unable to merge, this field is required

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, git-merge

I'm an ordinary bitbucket user who plays with `git push` `git pull` and `git merge` commands and never come across this weird situation.

Now I'm trying to merge my feature branch into my master branch and getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From bitbucket site follow these steps:

- Go to **Compare**
- Select **Destination** and **Source** branches
- Select **Compare** button
- Select **Merge** button on top right corner

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This error was a result of a bug that has now been fixed.

Comment: It would be useful to explain the bug (is it a bug in your work, or git or bitbucket?), and/or link to the bug report.

Comment: Apologies, it was a bug in Bitbucket. Interestingly, it was an [old bug](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8835/unable-to-merge-this-field-is-required) that resurfaced.